# Flutter app crashes when returning to previous screen

Tags: flutter, mobile, cross-platform

I have a Flutter app that populates a list of river gauge information and allows the user to select an item and view details in a chart, using the `charts_flutter` package.

I have used the chart successfully in the past with a FutureBuilder, and now it is being refactored to use a Provider. The view containing the chart works as expected, but when returning to the previous screen (the list of gauges) I receive an error after the list shows very briefly. The error is as follows.

[image]

This is the code that renders the chart view

```
class GaugeDetailChart extends StatefulWidget {
  GaugeReferenceModel referenceModel;
  GaugeDetailChart({this.referenceModel});

  @override
  _GaugeDetailChartState createState() => _GaugeDetailChartState();
}

class _GaugeDetailChartState extends State<GaugeDetailChart> {
  GaugeDetailViewModel viewModel;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _loadData();
    super.initState();
  }

  _loadData() {
      viewModel = Provider.of<GaugeDetailViewModel>(context, listen: false);
      viewModel.reloading = true;
      viewModel.setReferenceModel(widget.referenceModel);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: RLAppBar(
          titleText: Text('Gauge Detail'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Consumer<GaugeDetailViewModel>(
            builder: (context, model, child) => Stack(
              children: [
                Center(
                  child: Visibility(
                      visible: model.reloading,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Text('Loading details for'),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Text('${widget.referenceModel.gaugeName}'),
                          )
                        ],
                      )),
                ),

                // removing the following container resolves the exception

                Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .5,
                    alignment: Alignment(0.0, 0.0),
                    color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                    child: charts.TimeSeriesChart(
                      model.seriesFlowData,
                      animate: true,
                      animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                      primaryMeasureAxis: charts.NumericAxisSpec(
                          tickProviderSpec: charts.BasicNumericTickProviderSpec(
                              zeroBound: false,
                              dataIsInWholeNumbers: false,
                              desiredMaxTickCount: 8,
                              desiredMinTickCount: 5),
                          renderSpec: charts.GridlineRendererSpec(
                              tickLengthPx: 0, labelOffsetFromAxisPx: 5)),
                    )
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

The chart renders on the view correctly. The only time the error occurs is when exiting this view and returning to the previous view, which is performed using the NavigationController back button.

If I remove the Container that holds the chart, then returning to the previous view works without error. Something about the Container is causing the previous view to fail. The errors generated are very vague.

```
The following assertion was thrown building Overlay-[LabeledGlobalKey<OverlayState>#5f9d5](state: OverlayState#a6169(entries: [OverlayEntry#2b4ce(opaque: true; maintainState: false), OverlayEntry#eea3d(opaque: false; maintainState: true), OverlayEntry#c217d(opaque: true; maintainState: false), OverlayEntry#ae45e(opaque: false; maintainState: true), OverlayEntry#c7b73(opaque: true; maintainState: false), OverlayEntry#e34a6(opaque: false; maintainState: true)])):
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 5125 pos 14: '_dependents.isEmpty': is not true.


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  MaterialApp file:///Users/philiptownsend/Documents/projects.nosync/_Flutter/RiverLink/stream_watcher/lib/main.dart:32:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      InheritedElement.debugDeactivated.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5125:14)
#3      InheritedElement.debugDeactivated (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5127:6)
#4      _InactiveElements._deactivateRecursively.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2048:15)
#5      _InactiveElements._deactivateRecursively (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2050:6)
#6      ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4710:14)
```

Has anyone experienced anything like this before or can anyone make a recommendation on where to start looking or how to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure but why don't you try making the container a seperate widget and try
calling that widget. Maybe that resolves the issue

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried it both ways, same result. Really just taking shots in the dark at this point.

Comment: Same issue.. Have you resolved it ? @Pheepster